# Addin UDF recalculates after opening workbook even if Volatile is set to false

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, add-in, vba

I have an excel Add-in installed for my users. Inside the Add-in there are four User Defined Functions which are ment to get data from a SQL Server Database. Due to that the Application.Volatile is set to false in order to avoid unnecessary use that is very costly (it consumes time and generates lots of queries to the db what resuls in slowing down the server). Everything works almost as it should, almost because the Volatile false doesn't seem to work after a workbook is opened. Calculation is Manual so when I open the file and use either of recalculate options (f9, shift+f9, ctrl+alt+f9) it causes my non Volatile functions to recalculate even though no source cells were changed in any way. This situation doesn't happen when a UDF if placed in normal workbook. I've gone through excel options ticking many checkboxes, I've tried to switch between calculation options and even added some entries to the registry but nothing helps.
I would be very gratefull for any suggestions on that.

Comment: Would not work something like `AddIns("Your Add-In Name").Installed = False` during some code execution and turn it true when you are done? I use this to deactivate my SeoTools Add-in and it works perfect

Comment: FWIW, you should almost never use `Application.Volatile False` if that's what you mean? UDFs are not volatile by default.

Comment: The problem here is that the Add-in is not installed in a standard way. Due to some problems i had with it in multi user enviroment i pasted the add-in into each user's XLSTART folder so the only thing i can do do "uninstall" it temporarily is to brake link, but that would require some user actions that i would like to avoid.

Comment: I started with not having the Application.Volatile False line. I only added it afterwards to check if that may be the problem.

Comment: Why not use a flag - add an boolean argument to the UDF and a line that says if that argument is false then don't calculate anything and don't call the server. Then set that argument in the spreadsheet to point to a cell containing FALSE. When you want it to calculate just type TRUE in the cell

Comment: I tried to flag the moment of opening the workbook so that the first time a udf is called it checks the boolean(justOpened), skips the execution and sets the justOpened boolean to false. Unfortunately, the formula since it was called has to return some result so it that case it returns #VALUE! or 0 (depending on where it was checked for justOpened).

Comment: When you open a Workbook, the new one recalculates, and it activates your UDF i guess.  Try deactivating calculations before opnening the new workbook, or even disabling events. Maybe that could help. Check [How Excel determines the current mode of calculation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214395/how-excel-determines-the-current-mode-of-calculation)

Comment: Both options checked with negative result. I returned to the approach suggested by @HarassedDad and i found out that i can use Application.Caller object to catch the previous value. It worked!!! :) but excel is complaining about circular reference now. If i only could get rid of that somehow.

Comment: I was able to cancel the circular reference error msg by enabling the iterative calculation option in File->Options->Formulas. Even though the udf is checked a couple of Times per cel instead of one time(I can't do anything about it at least for now) it still takes close to zero time to return the result. I'll put that option to a controlled user test and I'll se what comes out of it.